# Text gradient animation after button press for multiple rows

Tags: javascript, html, css

Ey! When i press the Start button, an animation of the text stars and covers my text, changige it's colour. After i kept working, i noticed that if i have multiple rows ( or a bigger text) it triggers the animation for all lines in the same time, not one per turn as i expected it too. I've look into it and looks like it's a rougher problem then i've expected it to be. To be more precise, even if i kinda understood what i am supposed to do to implement it, other topics are not having a button included, and yeah, this changes quite everything ( The topics suggests in the first place to make multiple divs in html, but this is not possible as my button triggers one and add a class to it). Getting all of this, quite clear it overwhelmes my level of understading of CSS, HTMl and javascript. So, conclusioning:

- I'd like the animation to take each row on it's turn, not all at once. Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/angelsmall13/wdos8qve/

Somehelpfull topics but not enough for my problem that i've found here:
[How to create a CSS typing animation that spans multiple lines of text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46267355/how-to-create-a-css-typing-animation-that-spans-multiple-lines-of-text)

Any tip is appreciated
,   ,

```js
 function ani(){
 
    document.getElementById('target').className ='animated';

  }
```

```css
p {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 80;
  color: black;
  overflow: hidden;

  /* Same as before */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, darkgreen, darkgreen 50%, black 50%);

  /* Same as before */
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  background-position: 100%;

  /* Same as before */
  transition: background-position 10000ms ease;
}
.animated{
  background-position: 0 100%;
}
```

```html
<button type = "button" id= "ST" onclick= "ani()" >asd</button><br><br><br><br>
<p href="#a" id="target">Das Problem ist recht einfach, aber ich bin ein bisschen unerfahren in CSS, um es zu beheben. In dem Code, den ich unten anheften werde, beginnt die Animation, wenn der Code schwebt.</p> <br>
<audio id="audio" src="https://k15xf2.webwave.dev/lib/k15xf2/Prob1-kgs9f12v.mp3"></audio>
```

[CSS loads animations on multiple lines at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36758976/css-loads-animations-on-multiple-lines-at-the-same-time)

Comment: This article should help you out with your issue...https://www.sitepoint.com/event-bubbling-javascript/https://www.sitepoint.com/event-bubbling-javascript/    You are experiencing an onclick event bubbling effect...

Comment: Thank you for sharing and i'll deffinetely look into it, but as for a first view, it gets over my power of understanding  javas/css  :/